# “unable to get local issuer certificate” and “tlsv1 unrecognized name”

Tags: opensuse, php, curl, openssl

I am having a problem with the Paypal IPN postback verification. The problem came up a month ago, I believe when Paypal updated their security standards and their certificates.

My website is running Magento 1.8.1.0 that uses php-curl under the hood.
It runs openSUSE 12.3 and:

```
PHP 5.3.17
Apache 2.2.29
mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.33
OpenSSL 1.0.1j
```

The curl version installed is:

```
curl -V
curl 7.28.1 (x86_64-suse-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.28.1 OpenSSL/1.0.1j zlib/1.2.7 libidn/1.25 libssh2/1.4.3
Protocols: dict file ftp ftps gopher http https imap imaps ldap ldaps pop3 pop3s rtsp scp sftp smtp smtps telnet tftp 
Features: AsynchDNS GSS-Negotiate IDN IPv6 Largefile NTLM NTLM_WB SSL libz TLS-SRP
```

I enabled curl logs and it seems that the Paypal IPN endpoint (https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr) is answering me with a HTTP 500 error:

```
< HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
< Date: Fri, 14 Oct 2016 09:44:18 GMT
< Server: Apache/2.2.29 (Linux/SUSE)
< Vary: accept-language,accept-charset
< Accept-Ranges: bytes
< Connection: close
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
< Content-Language: en
< X-Pad: avoid browser bug
< 
* Closing connection #0
* About to connect() to www.paypal.com port 443 (#0)
* Trying 23.223.77.167...
* connected
* Connected to www.paypal.com (23.223.77.167) port 443 (#0)
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
* CAfile: none
CApath: /etc/ssl/certs/
* error:14077458:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:tlsv1 unrecognized name
* Closing connection #0
```

I tried to test the issue from the command line (I don't know if this output is meaningful):

```
openssl s_client -connect paypal.com:443
CONNECTED(00000003)
depth=1 C = US, O = DigiCert Inc, OU = www.digicert.com, CN = DigiCert SHA2 High Assurance Server CA
verify error:num=20:unable to get local issuer certificate
verify return:0
---
Certificate chain
 0 s:/C=US/ST=California/L=San Jose/O=PayPal, Inc./OU=PayPal Production/CN=paypal.com
   i:/C=US/O=DigiCert Inc/OU=www.digicert.com/CN=DigiCert SHA2 High Assurance Server CA
 1 s:/C=US/O=DigiCert Inc/OU=www.digicert.com/CN=DigiCert SHA2 High Assurance Server CA
   i:/C=US/O=DigiCert Inc/OU=www.digicert.com/CN=DigiCert High Assurance EV Root CA
---
Server certificate
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
subject=/C=US/ST=California/L=San Jose/O=PayPal, Inc./OU=PayPal Production/CN=paypal.com
issuer=/C=US/O=DigiCert Inc/OU=www.digicert.com/CN=DigiCert SHA2 High Assurance Server CA
---
No client certificate CA names sent
---
SSL handshake has read 2791 bytes and written 663 bytes
---
New, TLSv1/SSLv3, Cipher is AES256-SHA256
Server public key is 2048 bit
Secure Renegotiation IS supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1.2
    Cipher    : AES256-SHA256
    Session-ID: 53D6D36E366DBA89D458ABABFB9A08E5A6C470A61DFF00C908B3C8EAB320DB3F
    Session-ID-ctx: 
    Master-Key: 782AB9DDB7319512EFAA3F1843D1E70013E3E8BD384C20584537878DA09B0D9F0E1D6CD39624DD0CDC2BC0DD96616469
    Key-Arg   : None
    PSK identity: None
    PSK identity hint: None
    SRP username: None
    Start Time: 1476950153
    Timeout   : 300 (sec)
    Verify return code: 20 (unable to get local issuer certificate)
---
```

This is the PHP code that is using php-curl:

```
 /**
     * Post back to PayPal to check whether this request is a valid one
     *
     * @param Zend_Http_Client_Adapter_Interface $httpAdapter
     */
    protected function _postBack(Zend_Http_Client_Adapter_Interface $httpAdapter)
    {
            $sReq = '';
            foreach ($this->_request as $k => $v) {
                $sReq .= '&'.$k.'='.urlencode($v);
            }
            $sReq .= "&cmd=_notify-validate";
            $sReq = substr($sReq, 1);
            $this->_debugData['postback'] = $sReq;
            $this->_debugData['postback_to'] = $this->_config->getPaypalUrl();

            $httpAdapter->setConfig(array('verifypeer' => $this->_config->verifyPeer));

            $httpAdapter->addOption(CURLOPT_SSLVERSION,6);//CURL_SSLVERSION_TLSv1_2

            $httpAdapter->write(Zend_Http_Client::POST, $this->_config->getPaypalUrl(), '1.1', array(
                'Connection: close', 'User-Agent: XXXXXXXX'
            ), $sReq);
            try {
                $response = $httpAdapter->read();
            } catch (Exception $e) {
                $this->_debugData['http_error'] = array('error' => $e->getMessage(), 'code' => $e->getCode());
                throw $e;
            }
            $this->_debugData['postback_result'] = $response;

            $response = preg_split('/^\r?$/m', $response, 2);
            $response = trim($response[1]);
            if ($response != 'VERIFIED') {
                throw new Exception('PayPal IPN postback failure. See ' . self::DEFAULT_LOG_FILE . ' for details.');
            }
            unset($this->_debugData['postback'], $this->_debugData['postback_result']);
    }
```

And:

```
/**
     * Array of CURL options
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $_options = array();

    /**
     * Apply current configuration array to transport resource
     *
     * @return Varien_Http_Adapter_Curl
     */
    protected function _applyConfig()
    {
        if (empty($this->_config)) {
            return $this;
        }

        // apply additional options to cURL
        foreach ($this->_options as $option => $value) {
            curl_setopt($this->_getResource(), $option, $value);
        }

        $verifyPeer = isset($this->_config['verifypeer']) ? $this->_config['verifypeer'] : 0;
        curl_setopt($this->_getResource(), CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, $verifyPeer);

        $verifyHost = isset($this->_config['verifyhost']) ? $this->_config['verifyhost'] : 0;
        curl_setopt($this->_getResource(), CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, $verifyHost);

        foreach ($this->_config as $param => $curlOption) {
            if (array_key_exists($param, $this->_allowedParams)) {
                curl_setopt($this->_getResource(), $this->_allowedParams[$param], $this->_config[$param]);
            }
        }
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Set array of additional cURL options
     *
     * @param array $options
     * @return Varien_Http_Adapter_Curl
     */
    public function setOptions(array $options = array())
    {
        $this->_options = $options;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Add additional option to cURL
     *
     * @param  int $option      the CURLOPT_* constants
     * @param  mixed $value
     * @return Varien_Http_Adapter_Curl
     */
    public function addOption($option, $value)
    {
        $this->_options[$option] = $value;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Set the configuration array for the adapter
     *
     * @param array $config
     * @return Varien_Http_Adapter_Curl
     */
    public function setConfig($config = array())
    {
        $this->_config = $config;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Connect to the remote server
     *
     * @deprecated since 1.4.0.0-rc1
     * @param string  $host
     * @param int     $port
     * @param boolean $secure
     * @return Varien_Http_Adapter_Curl
     */
    public function connect($host, $port = 80, $secure = false)
    {
        return $this->_applyConfig();
    }

    /**
     * Send request to the remote server
     *
     * @param string        $method
     * @param Zend_Uri_Http $url
     * @param string        $http_ver
     * @param array         $headers
     * @param string        $body
     * @return string Request as text
     */
    public function write($method, $url, $http_ver = '1.1', $headers = array(), $body = '')
    {
        if ($url instanceof Zend_Uri_Http) {
            $url = $url->getUri();
        }
        $this->_applyConfig();

        curl_setopt($this->_getResource(), CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
        $handle = fopen('/srv/www/htdocs/MascagniB2C/var/log/curl.log', 'a+');
        curl_setopt($this->_getResource(), CURLOPT_STDERR, $handle);

        // set url to post to
        curl_setopt($this->_getResource(), CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($this->_getResource(), CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        if ($method == Zend_Http_Client::POST) {
            curl_setopt($this->_getResource(), CURLOPT_POST, true);
            curl_setopt($this->_getResource(), CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $body);
        }
        elseif ($method == Zend_Http_Client::GET) {
            curl_setopt($this->_getResource(), CURLOPT_HTTPGET, true);
        }

        if (is_array($headers)) {
            curl_setopt($this->_getResource(), CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
        }

        /**
         * @internal Curl options setter have to be re-factored
         */
        $header = isset($this->_config['header']) ? $this->_config['header'] : true;
        curl_setopt($this->_getResource(), CURLOPT_HEADER, $header);

        return $body;
    }
```

Can you please guide me understanding where the problem lies in my openssl configuration (or am I looking in the wrong direction)? Am I missing a certificate?

---

### UPDATE

A suggested I tried running:

```
openssl s_client -CApath /etc/ssl/certs/ -connect paypal.com:443
CONNECTED(00000003)
depth=2 C = US, O = DigiCert Inc, OU = www.digicert.com, CN = DigiCert High Assurance EV Root CA
verify return:1
depth=1 C = US, O = DigiCert Inc, OU = www.digicert.com, CN = DigiCert SHA2 High Assurance Server CA
verify return:1
depth=0 C = US, ST = California, L = San Jose, O = "PayPal, Inc.", OU = PayPal Production, CN = paypal.com
verify return:1
---
Certificate chain
 0 s:/C=US/ST=California/L=San Jose/O=PayPal, Inc./OU=PayPal Production/CN=paypal.com
   i:/C=US/O=DigiCert Inc/OU=www.digicert.com/CN=DigiCert SHA2 High Assurance Server CA
 1 s:/C=US/O=DigiCert Inc/OU=www.digicert.com/CN=DigiCert SHA2 High Assurance Server CA
   i:/C=US/O=DigiCert Inc/OU=www.digicert.com/CN=DigiCert High Assurance EV Root CA
---
Server certificate
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
subject=/C=US/ST=California/L=San Jose/O=PayPal, Inc./OU=PayPal Production/CN=paypal.com
issuer=/C=US/O=DigiCert Inc/OU=www.digicert.com/CN=DigiCert SHA2 High Assurance Server CA
---
No client certificate CA names sent
---
SSL handshake has read 2791 bytes and written 663 bytes
---
New, TLSv1/SSLv3, Cipher is AES256-SHA256
Server public key is 2048 bit
Secure Renegotiation IS supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1.2
    Cipher    : AES256-SHA256
    Session-ID: 78A62BA404C7656931D4FA5658820B4000CD69DBB82BAEB8E725ADBBE2B3E9C0
    Session-ID-ctx: 
    Master-Key: 725C7887E3F5BABC6BF878DDD4C2F9A246A08382BB259C700E8D74C95FF75D6E98FF2979BBB8661C7525D36956397179
    Key-Arg   : None
    PSK identity: None
    PSK identity hint: None
    SRP username: None
    Start Time: 1476950900
    Timeout   : 300 (sec)
    Verify return code: 0 (ok)
---
```

Comment: try `openssl s_client -CApath /etc/ssl/certs/ -connect paypal.com:443` and let's see if the verify return code isn't 20.

Comment: I updated the answer, it seems that the Verify return code is ok...

Comment: Which version of curl are you using?

Comment: I am using curl 7.28.1 (I updated the question with curl -V output)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have to update your curl version, since your version of curl doesn't support TLSv1.2 for php ([source](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php#115993)). And PayPal is enforcing to use TLSv1.2([source](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/lifecycle/info-security-guidelines/))

Answer (score 2):

> `openssl s_client -connect paypal.com:443`

I'm not a web guy, so I can't help with the PHP. I can help with this command, and show you how to use OpenSSL for trouble shooting.

You want to use TLS 1.0 or above, and you want to use Server Name Indication (SNI). So the command should use `-servername` to enlist SNI, and `-tls1` to use TLS 1.0. You can even use `-tls1_2` if you like:

```
$ openssl s_client -connect paypal.com:443 -servername paypal.com -tls1
CONNECTED(00000005)
depth=1 C = US, O = DigiCert Inc, OU = www.digicert.com, CN = DigiCert SHA2 High Assurance Server CA
verify error:num=20:unable to get local issuer certificate
Server did acknowledge servername extension.
...
New, SSLv3, Cipher is AES256-SHA
Server public key is 2048 bit
Secure Renegotiation IS supported
No ALPN negotiated
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1
    Cipher    : AES256-SHA
    Session-ID: 78A62BA404C4AA8731D4FA5658820840A014955818597872E725ADBBE29AB06B
    Session-ID-ctx: 
    Master-Key: DCE1A463B22DEB10AEA4CECD6C89560502F1F67583C0DDDDF81B0FD99D31C83AE81AA484C32ADC6E312AEC8AB5FE86D1
    PSK identity: None
    PSK identity hint: None
    SRP username: None
    Start Time: 1478608307
    Timeout   : 7200 (sec)
    Verify return code: 20 (unable to get local issuer certificate)
    Extended master secret: no
```

You can clear the ***`Verify return code: 20 (unable to get local issuer certificate)`*** by using `-CAfile` with the *DigiCert High Assurance EV Root CA*. You can fetch it from [DigiCert Trusted Root Authority Certificates](https://www.digicert.com/digicert-root-certificates.htm). Once you fetch it, you need to convert it from DER to PEM.

```
$ wget https://www.digicert.com/CACerts/DigiCertHighAssuranceEVRootCA.crt
...

$ file DigiCertHighAssuranceEVRootCA.crt 
DigiCertHighAssuranceEVRootCA.crt: data

$ openssl x509 -in DigiCertHighAssuranceEVRootCA.crt -inform DER \
              -out DigiCertHighAssuranceEVRootCA.pem -outform PEM

$ file DigiCertHighAssuranceEVRootCA.pem 
DigiCertHighAssuranceEVRootCA.pem: ASCII text
```

Then issue the following. Notice it finishes with ***`Verify return code: 0 (ok)`***.

```
$ openssl s_client -connect paypal.com:443 -servername paypal.com -tls1 -CAfile DigiCertHighAssuranceEVRootCA.pem 
CONNECTED(00000005)
depth=2 C = US, O = DigiCert Inc, OU = www.digicert.com, CN = DigiCert High Assurance EV Root CA
verify return:1
depth=1 C = US, O = DigiCert Inc, OU = www.digicert.com, CN = DigiCert SHA2 High Assurance Server CA
verify return:1
depth=0 C = US, ST = California, L = San Jose, O = "PayPal, Inc.", OU = PayPal Production, CN = paypal.com
verify return:1
Server did acknowledge servername extension.
...
New, SSLv3, Cipher is AES256-SHA
Server public key is 2048 bit
Secure Renegotiation IS supported
No ALPN negotiated
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1
    Cipher    : AES256-SHA
    Session-ID: 53D6D36E366E7A68D458ABABFB9A08E5F1EC49287E6265D008B3C8EAB3098951
    Session-ID-ctx: 
    Master-Key: 13C070B784545ED1F11608E4871936CABF9BFC8A4320C025003ABE05320C3598342500BB12C90F89270B19D26D793A96
    PSK identity: None
    PSK identity hint: None
    SRP username: None
    Start Time: 1478608643
    Timeout   : 7200 (sec)
    Verify return code: 0 (ok)
    Extended master secret: no
```

---

Finally, all you need to do is tell PHP and cURL to use `DigiCertHighAssuranceEVRootCA.pem`. Your cURL command would probably be something like:

```
curl www.paypal.com:443 --tlsv1.0 --cacert DigiCertHighAssuranceEVRootCA.pem
```

I don't know what to do in PHP.